# Overriding the view_handler_field_node_link_edit

Tags: views

I have created a view using custom content type with edit link.I have to write some php code for edit link.Can i override views_handler_field_node_link_edit extends in my custom module?

```
    /**
     * Renders the link.
     */
    class views_handler_field_node_link_edit extends views_handler_field_node_link {
        function render_link($node, $values) {
        // Ensure user has access to edit this node.
            if (!node_access('update', $node)) {
                return;
            }

            $this->options['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
            $this->options['alter']['path'] = "node/$node->nid/edit";
            $this->options['alter']['query'] = drupal_get_destination();

            $text = !empty($this->options['text']) ? $this->options['text'] : t('edit');
            return $text;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post will help you out http://thereisamoduleforthat.com/content/recipe-extending-views-handlers-without-subclassing